# Check if an element exists in a nodelist returned from querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html

I have an nodeList returned from querySelectorAll() which has only checked checkboxes:

```
 var choiceInputs= document.querySelectorAll('.form-checkbox-input:checked);
```

Another nodelist is present which has all the checkboxes

```
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.form-checkbox-input')
```

I want to check if checkbox is present in choiceInputs or not.How can i do that?

Comment: Doesn't it have to? `choiceinputs` will always be a subset of `checkbox`.

Comment: `.form-checkbox-input:checked` is always a subset of `.form-checkbox-input` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter out the checked and unchecked boxes using `Array#filter`.

You can also add in a change listener wherein you can update the checked and unchecked arrays.

```js
const allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

let
  uncheckedBoxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes).filter(cb => !cb.checked),
  checkedBoxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes).filter(cb => cb.checked);

console.log("Unchecked Boxes", uncheckedBoxes);
console.log("Checked Boxes", checkedBoxes);

allCheckboxes.forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    uncheckedBoxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes).filter(cb => !cb.checked);
    checkedBoxes = Array.from(allCheckboxes).filter(cb => cb.checked);
    console.clear();
    console.log("Unchecked Boxes", uncheckedBoxes);
    console.log("Checked Boxes", checkedBoxes);
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="apple">Apple</label>
<input id="apple" type="checkbox" checked/>
<label for="mango">Mango</label>
<input id="mango" type="checkbox" />
<label for="banana">Banana</label>
<input id="banana" type="checkbox" checked/>
```